# how to fill the table with text fields of form using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have two forms. The first form `#form1` contains two texts fields (month and year) and a search button. The second form `#form2` contains a table.

I want when i click on button search, hide form1 and show form2, mean, want to fill this table by year and by month of the fields of the form 1.

**index.balde.php**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
    <div class="row" id="form1">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class=" col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
                <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                    <label for="titre">Annee</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-5">
                    <input type="text" name="annee" id="annee" class="form-control">
                </div>
           </div>

           <div class=" col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
               <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                   <label for="titre">Mois</label>
               </div>
               <div class="form-group col-md-5">
                   <input type="text" name="mois" id="mois" class="form-control">
               </div>
           </div>
           <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-5">
               <button class="btn btn-theme " type="submit" id="hide" >cherche</button>
           </div>
       </div>
       <div class="row" id="form2">
           <table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
               <thead>
                   <tr>
                       <th>name</th>
                       <th>year</th>
                       <th>month</th>
                   </tr>
               </thead>
               <tbody id="b">
                   @foreach($salaries as $salarie)
                   <tr>
                       <td>{{ $salarie->nom }}</td>
                       <td><input type="hidden" class='year' class="form-control" /></td>
                       <td><input type="hidden" class='month' class="form-control" /></td>
                   </tr>
                   @endforeach
               </tbody>
           </table>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("#form2").hide();
    let now = new Date();
    let year = now.getFullYear();
    let month = ("0" + (now.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
    $('#annee').val(year);
    $('#mois').val(month); 

    $("#hide").click(function(){
        $("#form2").show();
        $("#form1").hide();
        let annee = $("#annee").val();
        let mois = $("#mois").val();
        $('#year').val(annee);
        $('#month').val(annee); 
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the HTML code you provided, `#form2` is inside `#form1`. Because of that, hiding `#form1` will also hide `#form2`.

Also, when you click the `#hide` button, you are selecting the table cells with `$('#year')` and `$('#month')`, but you should select by class, as your inputs are:

```
<td><input type="hidden" class='year' class="form-control" /></td>
<td><input type="hidden" class='month' class="form-control" /></td>
```

So, it would suffice with:

```
$("#hide").click(function(){
    $("#form2").show();
    $("#form1").hide();
    let annee = $("#annee").val();
    let mois = $("#mois").val();
    $('.year').val(annee);
    $('.month').val(annee); 
});
```

Also note that, as your table inputs have `type="hidden"` they will not be shown.